# Create Kubernetes Pod Network Map

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I am looking to map out various network connections between pods in a namespace to understand which pod is talking to which other pods. Is there a way to query the etcd to get this information?

Comment: No, there is no way to get this from etcd. You could use Distributed tracing and generate a map from that... or possibly use Network Policiies but I dont know if there is a tool to visualize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Weave Scope](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope) to make a graphical map of your Kubernetes cluster.

It will generates a map of your process, containers and hosts in real time. You can also get logs from containers and run some diagnostic commands via WEB-UI.

To install on Kubernetes you can run:

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/scope.yaml?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

After launch you don't need to configure anything, Scope will listen you pods and network and make a map of you network.

Answer (score 9):

There are many tools to visualize k8s topology.

In order of Github stars:

- Cockpit:

  - [Cockpit Project — Cockpit Project](https://cockpit-project.org/) Cockpit makes GNU/Linux discoverable. See your server in a web browser and perform system tasks with a mouse. It’s easy to start containers, administer storage, configure networks, and inspect logs.  [image: Storage screenshot]
- [Weave Scope](https://www.weave.works/oss/scope/) (Github: [weaveworks/scope](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope)) is a troubleshooting and monitoring tool for Docker and Kubernetes clusters. It can automatically generate applications and infrastructure topologies which can help you to identify application performance bottlenecks easily. You can deploy Weave Scope as a standalone application on your local server/laptop, or you can choose the Weave Scope Software as a Service (SaaS) solution on Weave Cloud. With Weave Scope, you can easily group, filter or search containers using names, labels, and/or resource consumption. :

  - [image]
- [spekt8/spekt8: Visualize your Kubernetes cluster in real time](https://github.com/spekt8/spekt8) :

  - SPEKT8 is a new visualization tool for your Kubernetes clusters. It automatically builds logical topologies of your application and infrastructure, which enable your SRE and Ops team to intuitively understand, monitor, and control your containerized, microservices based application. Simply deploy our containerized application directly into your Kubernetes cluster.
  - [image]
- KubeView (Github: [benc-uk/kubeview: Kubernetes cluster visualiser and graphical explorer](https://github.com/benc-uk/kubeview) )

  - [image]
  - KubeView displays what is happening inside a Kubernetes cluster, it maps out the API objects and how they are interconnected. Data is fetched real-time from the Kubernetes API. The status of some objects (Pods, ReplicaSets, Deployments) is colour coded red/green to represent their status and health. [image]
- [Kubernetes Topology Graph](https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/topology-graph):

  - Provides a simple force directed topology graph for kubernetes items.
  - [image: Kubernetes Topology Graph]

Comment: weave scope worked great! SPEKT8 did not work for some reason.